# Pass a ComboBox as a parameter

Tags: vba, combobox, outlook

I need to pass a ComboBox to a method in a different class module.  First I defined the method in the class module as:

```
Public Sub initializeCombo(ByVal s As String, ByRef c As ComboBox)
```

And called it from a form:

```
initializeCombo(s, frmMyForm.cboBox)
```

This results in a type mismatch.  This works if I define the method in the code behind the form, but not in a separate class module.

Comment: what is `msforms`?  Is that an alias for `System.Windows.Forms`?  Do you have something similar in your class module?  Is it defined the same way in both places?

Comment: I originally did not include msforms.  I declared as a Combo Box.  Adding it was a suggestion I found on a forum but I just realized the suggestion applied to excel exclusively where there was an excel.combobox that took precedence.  I will edit my original post to remove this.  The error was the same.

Comment: Ah, Outlook VBA.  This is starting to make sense.

Comment: Try to replace `ByRef c As ComboBox` with `c As Variant`, then set a breakpoint on the first line and check on the watch window what is being passed. This usually helps understand what's going on when the object passed is not the expected type.

Comment: I have done as @stenci suggests and the type is Variant/Object/OptionButton.  I do not understand why this would result in a type mismatch.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: It's a mismatch because `OptionButton` is not `ComboBox`. Try to change it into `ByRef c As OptionButton`

Comment: @Stenci wow...not sure what I was thinking.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a mismatch because `OptionButton` is not `ComboBox`. Try to change it into `ByRef c As OptionButton`.

You can figure that out by replacing `ByRef c As ComboBox` with `c As Variant`, then set a breakpoint on the first line and check on the watch window what is being passed. This usually helps understand what's going on when the object passed is not the expected type.